# Access localstorage in App.config

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I understand that in `app.config` only providers and constants are injectable in configuration blocks but i can't find any valid solution for my case.

I have an `app.config` like :

```
angular
    .module('app.core')      
    .config(initDebug)
    .config(initRouter)
    .config(initStorage)
```

All that i want is to inject the `common` service : 
       
        `angular 
        .module('app.core')
        .factory('common', ($location, $q, $rootScope, messageService, globalData) => {
            return new Common($location, $q, $rootScope, messageService, globalData);
        });`

I have a ui-router in this `app-config` and i want to make a breadcrumb with accesed object like :

```
state('class-add?itemId', {
            url: '/classAdd?itemId',
            templateUrl: '/app/classes/class-add.partial.html',
            controller: 'ClassesController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',                
            ncyBreadcrumb: {                  
                 ---> here goes the common.SelectedClass (from localstorage)
            }                
        })
```

Any help ?

Answer (score -1):

`angular-local-storage` is a great solution for Angular JS + Local Storage requirements

```
myApp.config(function (localStorageServiceProvider) {
  localStorageServiceProvider
    .setPrefix('myApp')
    .setStorageType('sessionStorage')
    .setNotify(true, true)
});
```

Comment: angular-local-storage's localStorageServiceProvider does not implement methods to get data from local storage.